# Where to find default bindings for special keys

Tags: debian, xorg, xfce

My keyboard has special keys, like for sound muting or launching the web browser. With my stock Xfce 4.10 installation on Debian testing (Jessie) these keys are automatically mapped, so I didn't needed to configure them manually.

However, I would like to change some of these bindings to custom commands. I might do so via the keyboard settings in Xfce, but I would rather change it the "official" way.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're suppose to just use the standard dialog to do this, accessible under: *Settings* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts*.

[image: ss of dialog]

You can read all about this here in the Xfce official docs: "[Xfce Docs » Core » Settings Manager » Keyboard](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/keyboard)".